# Which atoms are required by Biopython's calc_dihedral() to calculate all 3 dihedral angles?

Tags: python, biopython

I want to calculate all the three dihedral angles in a residue.

`calc_dihedral(atom1, atom2, atom3, atom4)` of Biopython requires vector coordinates of four atoms as arguments and returns an output of a single value. I'm not sure which of the three angles output represents.

Please suggest which atoms in the residue are required to calculate which angle and in what order the atom coordinates should be given in the function as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The dihedral angle is "twisting" along the bond of atoms 2 and 3 in a chain of four atoms 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Two dihedral angles psi and phi are used in Ramachandran Plots, and getting those is easy in Biopython - see http://www.warwick.ac.uk/go/peter_cock/python/ramachandran/calculate/

Which *three* angles are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for phi, psi and omega angle. Can't I use calc_dihedral() function of biopython for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, if you give it the four atoms which define the dihedral angle omega.

Answer (score 1):

We need backbone atoms only N,CA,C. so for the protein chain we get N,CA,**C,N,CA,C**,N,CA,C,N,CA,C.

we need to define them in plane, to find out the angle we need two planes (plane1: C,N,CA)(plane2: N,CA,C). we neglect the N,CA for first residue. Consider the bolded atoms only. so you submit the bolded atoms (3 atoms of one residue and 4th atom from the second residue.) I dont know about omega.